# passing classes between view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm building a Quiz app, and I'm trying to reduce the amount of view controllers by having one view controller act as the Question view controller. This is the view controller where the user is taking the quiz.

I have multiple question banks that are filled with questions specific to a category. These question banks are .swift files, which I believe are classified as classes, they look like this:

```
import Foundation

class QuestionBank {

var list = [Questions]()

init() {

    let item = Questions(text: "what does blah blah blah mean?", correctAnswer: "blah blah", textA: "blah blah blah", textB: "blah", textC: "blah bla", textD: "blee blah" )

    list.append(item)

    list.append(Questions(text: "this is a question?", correctAnswer: "correct answer", textA: "examplea", textB: "exampleb", textC: "examplec", textD: "exampled"))

    list.append(Questions(text: ".......

    list.append(Questions(text: ".......

    list.append(Questions(text: ".......

    }


}
```

Below is just the first line of the QuestionViewController but it shows that var allQuestions holds GeographyQuestionBank. GeographyQuestionBank looks like the QuestionBank example code above (but with actual questions lol)

```
import UIKit

import Foundation

class QuestionsViewController: UIViewController {

var allQuestions = GeographyQuestionBank()

...
```

I understand how to pass things between view controllers by using the prepare(for segue:... ) function. But Im not sure how to pass a class to the allQuestions variable. Is that possible?

I hope this made sense, If not please send a message and I'll try to explain it better. But I just want to be able to pass question bank classes to the QuestionsViewController depending on the category picked on the previous view controller.

Comment: need more explanation what actually you have to pass any particular question or list of question, as there is no specification about any category in above code

Comment: @jaydeepvyas thanks for the response. In the first example, where it says "class QuestionBank" that is just an example. Each question bank holds a list of questions to a specific category. So say on the previous view controller there are 4 buttons to choose from.  "Geography", "History", "Animals" and "Math". Each of those categories has a its own question bank i.e HistoryQuestionBank.swift, AnimalsQuestionBank.swift, etc. So I want to pass var allQuestions on the QuestionsViewController a question bank depending on the category/button picked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It become very simple if you pass the questions array to the Second view Controller like below.

**FIRST VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
import UIKit

 class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

        var selectedCategoryQuestions :[Questions] = []
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
        @IBAction func onClickBtnHistoryQuestions(_ sender: Any)
    {
        //Fill your array with History Question
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSecondVC", sender: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func onClickBtnGeoQuestions(_ sender: Any) {
        //Fill your array with Geo Question
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSecondVC", sender: nil)
    }

 if (segue.identifier == "yourSecondVC")
        {
            let destVC:yourSecondVC =  segue.destination as! yourSecondVC
            destVC.questionList = selectedCategoryQuestions

        }
    }
```

**SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
 class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

        var questionList:[Questions] = []
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            println(questionList)  //You get selected list here
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in Swift you don't pass your classes themselves to view controllers as you can instantiate them anywhere (usually) perhaps you're referring to passing an *instance* of a class to different view controllers?

If your questions are static i.e. you're just listing them by category and not changing them after they're put in, you don't really need a class of them. You can just put them in a `struct` or `enum` so that they're publicly accessible wherever you need them.

There's no need to pass the instance of the questions or all questions to different view controllers. If you gather them all in your `allQuestions` variable, you can just iterate or remove the elements depending on your implementation

Comment: thanks for the response. What would gathering all the instances in the allQuestions variable look like? and then how would an instance be picked depending on the category picked on the previous view controller?